# Delimiters in javascript

Tags: javascript, delimiter

What I want now is not be show out the delimiter, when I print out the sentence from my database. For example in the database, one element store `"Jane likes#to#play the#piano"`. So it will actually separate into 4 string elements. However, doing any function first like drag and drop the string array elements. I want to print out the sentence first "Jane likes to play the piano." in order for the person to memorise the sentence, so that they can start playing the game.

The code below displays "Jane likes#to#play the#piano." instead of what I want which is this "Jane likes to play the piano."

`$output` is the sentence retrieved from the database.

```
<script>
 //Parses the variable from php to this Javascript part
 var js_var = "<?php echo $output ?>";

 //document.write(js_var);

 //Splits the string when the delimiter # is detected
 var split_str= js_var.split("#");


 //var js_var = "Try123";
 //displays original string
 document.writeln(js_var+"<br >"+"<br >");


 //sent to shuffle(o) function to scramble the elements
 var shuffle_str = shuffle(split_str);

 //displays each of the shuffled string array elements
 for (i=0;i<shuffle_str.length;i++)
 {
   document.write(shuffle_str[i] + "<br >");
 }

 //document.writeln(js_var);

 function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
   for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
   return o;
 };
</script>
```

Comment: So you are looking for [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Comment: @chrona I am using # is split the sentence. So now i don't want the print out to display this sign # only the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

After spliting just use
`yourString = yourString.join(' ')`
too put them back together (with a space).

Or instead just use a regular expression instead of splitting it `yourString = yourString.replace(/#/, ' ')`.